# function creating boxplots with brackets in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, dunn.test

Is there a function in R which can create boxplots and prints in addition brackets around those groups, which do not show significant differences using a pairwise multiple comparison test (e.g. Dunn's test)?

The result should be similar to this picture:

[image]